# Sort any one of a few arbitrary classes that all contain a certain parameter

Tags: c#, class, generics

I have a lot of classes that are all certain to contain an int called val, which I'd like to sort them on.    They look something like this:

```
public class KeyString
{
    public string key;
    public int val;
}
public class KeySprite
{
    public Sprite key;
    public int val;
}
public class KeyInt
{
    public int key;
    public int val;
}
```

Currently I sort them like this:

```
public static List<KeyString> SortKeyString(List<KeyString> l){
        l.Sort((a,b) => a.val.CompareTo(b.val));
        return l;
    }
public static List<KeySprite> SortKeySprite(List<KeySprite> l){
        l.Sort((a,b) => a.val.CompareTo(b.val));
        return l;
    }
public static List<KeyInt> SortKeyInt(List<KeyInt> l){
        l.Sort((a,b) => a.val.CompareTo(b.val));
        return l;
    }
```

This ... works, in the sense that it gets the right answer, but to me this feels like potentially unnecessary code duplication.  Is it possible to write a single sort method that could sort a list of any of these classes?

(Note:  I'm only sorting lists of a single class at a time - We're not trying to combine two different classes here.)

Comment: Use an interface and a generic method.

Comment: Your classes look like a built-in KeyValuePair. Why not using that if it makes sense. A bit of context would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class like:

```
public class KeyBase
{
    public int val;
}
```

now Inherit all your classes from it:

```
public class KeyString : KeyBase
{
    public string key;
}
public class KeySprite : KeyBase
{
    public Sprite key;
}
public class KeyInt : KeyBase
{
    public int key;
}

public static List<T> SortKey<T>(List<T> l) where T: KeyBase
{
    l.Sort((a,b) => a.val.CompareTo(b.val));
    return l;
}
```

If the only different in your classes is the type of `key` variable, you can do something like:

```
public class Key<T>
{
    public T key;
    public int val;
}

public static List<Key<T>> Sort<T>(List<Key<T>> l)
{
        l.Sort((a,b) => a.val.CompareTo(b.val));
        return l;
}

var stringKeys = new List<Key<string>> { ... };
var intKeys = new List<Key<int>> { ... };
var SpriteKeys = new List<Key<Sprite>> { ... };
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y4oVw0)

Comment: @Everyone_Else: You could also use _properties_ rather than _fields_ in your class definition.  Then all your classes could implement an _interface_ like `public interface IHaveAValue { int val {get;}}` and you could sort by that.  Remember, you can implement that interface any way you want, so you could have a class with an int property not named `val`, but that explicitly implements `IHaveAValue.val`

Comment: @Flydog57 I always use properties in this case, but didn't want to alter OP code much, to emphasize only on what my code has to offer.